# In FF45 FormData with empty file input didnt set Content-Type

Tags: firefox, multipartform-data, form-data

Bugs started when clients had migrating to FF 45. They tryed to submit forms with empty file inputs and it fail.
I detected that, if you submit form by AJAX with `FormData`, and it have empty file input - FF will not set `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`

I created minimal script to demonstrate this bug:

```js
var fileInput = document.createElement('input');
fileInput.type = 'file';
fileInput.name = 'fileData';

var form = document.createElement('form');
form.method = 'post';
form.enctype = 'multipart/form-data';
form.appendChild(fileInput);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/url");
xhr.send(new FormData(form));
```

I use standart FF45 on windows.

Comment: Why would it set `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` when there isn't any content to describe?

Comment: I cant set `Content-Type` from JS

Comment: Why does that matter? There's still no data to describe the content-type of.

Comment: `Content-Type` must be defined, otherwise my server fail

Comment: Perhaps that's a problem that should be solved on the server.

Comment: Simple analogy: the police always shall protect the innocent, but not always it can make. Perhaps, сan be to me will take care of it? No, thanks )) We have standarts and when I use standart - I want good job and no hacks ))

Comment: Actually, I hoped that this message will be seen by the FF developers

Comment: I had this issue the other day and can give some more detail. The only noticeable difference between the request for me in FF 45 and Chrome is: FF 45 does not have `filename="" Content-Type: application/octet-stream` in its request against the file upload file but Chrome does. @Quentin Yes this might be a server issue more than FF 45, but there in lies the question. In my scenario PHP's $_FILES array is not getting populated from the FF 45 request, which is causing issues with Validation. So is FF 45 request valid and legal and PHP (Apache) interpretation wrong or the other way round?

Comment: In this case, I think that the server works correctly, because it can't get field type. IMHO, a problem in the wrong request of FF

Comment: Same problem here with Firefox 45.0.1. I can't use your hack because I need to send empty file inputs. Don't know what to do.

Comment: I did a writeup on this issue here: http://www.hydrogen18.com/blog/fixing-what-isnt-broke.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt find any information about this bug, and use hack: delete empty file inputs before submited id:

```js
var fileInput = document.createElement('input');
fileInput.type = 'file';
fileInput.name = 'fileData';

var form = document.createElement('form');
form.method = 'post';
form.enctype = 'multipart/form-data';
form.appendChild(fileInput);

// Filter empty file inputs
var childNodes = form.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]');
for (var i=0;i<childNodes.length;i++) {
  if (childNodes[i].files.length === 0) {
    childNodes[i].parentElement.removeChild(childNodes[i]);
  }
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/url");
xhr.send(new FormData(form));
```